# Filenames with spaces

Tags: php

I am running PHP locally (no webserver involved at all). I am having trouble accessing a file with spaces in the path.

My bare bones case is

```
$indexFile = "file:///Users/username/Documents/My Folder/test.txt";
echo file_exists($indexFile);
```

or:

```
$indexFile = "file:///Users/username/Documents/My‰20Folder/test.txt";
echo file_exists($indexFile);
```

AFAICT this latter case is a well-formed file scheme URI. It's exactly what appears in the browser location field if I drag the file in there.

URI's without spaces don't have any problem. Unfortunately I am not at liberty to change "My Folder" to "MyFolder", and besides, I want to find a solution.

I tried using urlencode, rawurlencode, escapeshellarg, I've tried replacing %20 with a backslash-escaped space `"My\ Folder"` but none of this works. I've also hunted through google and stackoverflow, but while there are many suggstions, the question remains unanswered:

How to access an arbitrary file (on the local host) using a path which contains spaces?

Comment: try getting rid of `file://` in the beginning and see what happens

Comment: btw, if neither of those work and worst comes to worst, try adding "Users/username/Documents/My Folder/" to your PATH for the system and then just reference the file by name ("test.txt") in your settings file.

Comment: Also, I recommend `var_dump()` instead of `echo` to output the value of a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first `file://` from the first code snippet. It'll work.

```
$indexFile = "file:///Users/username/Documents/My Folder/test.txt";
echo file_exists(str_replace("file://", "", $indexFile));
```

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a Mac OSX file system and so this should work:

```
$indexFile = "/Users/username/Documents/My Folder/test.txt"
echo file_exists("${indexFile}");
```